# Jupyter notebook cell is not printing anything

Tags: python, scikit-learn, jupyter-notebook

I'm working on some ML classification problem on jupyter notebook. consider following code

## Code (cell 1)

```
# all imports goes here
w.filterwarnings('ignore')
# define scoring method
scoring = 'accuracy'

# Define models to train
names = ["Nearest Neighbors", "Gaussian Process",
         "Decision Tree", "Random Forest", "Neural Net", "AdaBoost",
         "Naive Bayes", "SVM Linear", "SVM RBF", "SVM Sigmoid"]

classifiers = [
    KNeighborsClassifier(n_neighbors = 3),
    GaussianProcessClassifier(1.0 * RBF(1.0)),
    DecisionTreeClassifier(max_depth=5),
    RandomForestClassifier(max_depth=5, n_estimators=10, max_features=1),
    MLPClassifier(alpha=1),
    AdaBoostClassifier(),
    GaussianNB(),
    SVC(kernel = 'linear'), 
    SVC(kernel = 'rbf'),
    SVC(kernel = 'sigmoid')
]

models = zip(names, classifiers)

# evaluate each model in turn
results = []
names = []

for name, model in models:
    kfold = model_selection.KFold(n_splits=10, random_state = seed)
    cv_results = model_selection.cross_val_score(model, X_train, y_train, cv=kfold, scoring=scoring)
    results.append(cv_results)
    names.append(name)
    msg = "%s: %f (%f)" % (name, cv_results.mean(), cv_results.std())
    print(msg)
```

This cell executes properly and prints all the models with accuracy as expected.

## Code (cell 2)

```
for name, model in models:][1]][1]
    model.fit(X_train, y_train)
    predictions = model.predict(X_test)
    print(name)
    print(accuracy_score(y_test, predictions))
    print(classification_report(y_test, predictions))
```

But this cell is not printing anything. also there are no errors/warnings.
[image: See this]

### Update

I Edited the code in cell and colab showing me error as

> Session/line number not unique in our database
> [image: updatate]

Comment: You say the second cell is executing but not showing output. How long are you waiting? it could be that you just need to be a bit more patient waiting for model.fit to return, depending on the size of X_train and Y_train.

Comment: When I run it after just few seconds it shows the cell number in place of *

Comment: Are you able to run a different cell doing something trivial afterwards? (ex: print("hello")). I have seen this behavior before when a cell causes the kernel to crash.

Comment: If I add print(‘cell’) before the for loop then its printing the cell but not executing the for loop

Comment: I meant make a third cell with just the print statement. After executing the second cell, can you still make the third cell print? If so, I would check to make sure that models is not empty, and after that add print statements before model.fit and model.predict.

Comment: I hosted the notebook on colab you want me to share link ?

Comment: "Session/line number not unique in our database" is a warning thrown by Colab runtime and has nothing to do with your code. This exact warning has occured to me several times, after mounting the drive and reloading the page.



Also, the for loop is not iterating over the object 'models'. I'm pretty sure that the object 'models' is empty.

Comment: I guess you are right list models is becoming empty after first cell ? but why ? I did not change anything ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thanks to @knoop , I zipped the names, classifier in final cell and that solved my problem.

```
models = zip(names, classifiers)
for name, model in models:
    model.fit(X_train, y_train)
    predictions = model.predict(X_test)
    print(name)
    print(accuracy_score(y_test, predictions))
    print(classification_report(y_test, predictions))
```